# Google docs viewer not working

Tags: google-docs

Using this code:

```
<iframe height="780" src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://ruh.kz/sites/default/files/doc/ritorika.pdf&embedded=true" style="border: none;" width="600"></iframe>
```

But all the time im getting this annoying message:
Sorry, we are unable to retrieve the document for viewing or you don't have permission to view the document.

By the way, i have read about ISP might block google docs. But i've checked another sites with google docs viewer and they seemed to work perfectly.

Comment: when trying to view just the link you have in your url , it says : you don't have permission to view the document , so first change your pdf's permission

Comment: Ok, it was the error in the url path. Another question: can i embed pdf in google docs through google docs viewer. (so i won't upload it on my server).

Comment: How long have you used this google api? and how has it worked for you? "viewer" Do you pay for this service?

Answer (score -1):

to embed your pdf without putting it in your server , just login to your gmail and upload it in google docs then copy the link and put it in your iframe's src

Comment: Hi, I am also getting the same error as above. I had uploaded the pdf file in my server and given the url in google docs viewer as above. But it is showing the same error message as above. How do i get rid of it.??

Answer (score -1):

first you try with online version to view your file if it shows your file,you gave wrong url to iframe,if viewer does not show your file at embedded version and online version check your file size,file url and file permissions to viewer can reach your document.You can try your url, for example http://www.foo.com/bar.pdf paste in your browser,if url is right browser shows the file...